# PHP array_unique() - do some logic first before reducing the array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have this array data:

```
array:3 [
  0 => array:5 [
    "menu_id" => 7
    "menu_name" => "Kasagbutan Meals"
    "menu_price" => "100.00"
    "qty" => "1"
    "special_instructions" => ""
  ]
  1 => array:5 [
    "menu_id" => 7
    "menu_name" => "Kasagbutan Meals"
    "menu_price" => "100.00"
    "qty" => "1"
    "special_instructions" => ""
  ]
  2 => array:5 [
    "menu_id" => 6
    "menu_name" => "Coke"
    "menu_price" => "50.00"
    "qty" => "1"
    "special_instructions" => ""
  ]
]
```

When I ran it with `array_unique()`, the data becomes like this:

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:5 [
    "menu_id" => 7
    "menu_name" => "Kasagbutan Meals"
    "menu_price" => "100.00"
    "qty" => "1"
    "special_instructions" => ""
  ]
  2 => array:5 [
    "menu_id" => 6
    "menu_name" => "Coke"
    "menu_price" => "50.00"
    "qty" => "1"
    "special_instructions" => ""
  ]
]
```

How can I add the `qty` before it reduces the array? I want to add the `qty` of the removed array item. So basically, the ideal array result should be like this:

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:5 [
    "menu_id" => 7
    "menu_name" => "Kasagbutan Meals"
    "menu_price" => "100.00"
    "qty" => "2" ----> THIS BECOMES 2 BECAUSE THE OTHER ITEM HAS A QTY OF 1.
    "special_instructions" => ""
  ]
  2 => array:5 [
    "menu_id" => 6
    "menu_name" => "Coke"
    "menu_price" => "50.00"
    "qty" => "1"
    "special_instructions" => ""
  ]
]
```

Comment: Are you obtaining that data from a relational/nosql database?

Comment: What makes one entry equal to another? Just the `menu_id` property or does it take into account other properties too?

Comment: @Phil - If they have the same values in the following keys:
- menu_id
- menu_name
- menu_price
- special_instructions
So basically all EXCEPT `qty`

Comment: So you're saying entries can have the same `menu_id` but different `menu_name`, `menu_price`, etc? What's the point in having a field named _"id"_ if it doesn't identify the record?

Comment: @Phil - Actually, No. Ideally if they have the same `menu_id` it will also have the same `menu_name`, `menu_price`, etc.. I am including `menu_id` because I am returning this data in the frontend and my JS code is doing some logic in this also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array_unique()` is simply a *reduce* operation. What you want is a slightly more complex one so use `array_reduce()`

```php
$exclude = array_flip(['qty']); // list of properties to exclude when creating a hash

$totals = array_reduce($arr, function($totals, $item) use ($exclude) {
    $id = array_diff_key($item, $exclude);
    ksort($id); // sort by key to always get the same order
    $hash = crc32(json_encode($id));
    if (array_key_exists($hash, $totals)) {
        $totals[$hash]['qty'] += $item['qty'];
    } else {
        $totals[$hash] = $item;
    }
    return $totals;
}, []);
```

This builds up a new array keyed by a hash of *identifying* values (everything except for `qty`) that, upon finding an entry it already knows about, increases the `qty`.

I've gone with a CRC32 hash of the JSON encoded string for speed. You can use just about any hashing / serialization combo though.

Demo ~ https://3v4l.org/YDsfc

Special nods to the following posts:

- [PHP best way to MD5 multi-dimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254220/php-best-way-to-md5-multi-dimensional-array)
- [Return all array elements except for a given key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147691/return-all-array-elements-except-for-a-given-key)

Comment: thanks for, but I tried adding a different value in the `special_instructions` but it combined it with the others that doesnt have a `special_instructions` value. This is before it ran through your code: https://pastebin.com/hG8C35Q0 noticed that the other has a value in `special_instructions`, this is AFTER your code: https://pastebin.com/sCu76Que Ideal output should be like this: https://pastebin.com/Gk5ttWEr